# Clear / erase a mistyped password in a terminal

Tags: command-line, terminal, password, line-editor

One thing that annoys me using Linux's terminal is when I have to type a invisble password, like when you run ssh the terminal I was wondering if there's a way to clear/erase the invisible password without relying on backspace or pressing enter key to try again

Comment: unclear what you are asking

Comment: Typing the Ctrl-U key combination will erase the entire line of input even if echo is turned off.

Comment: `Ctrl+w` if you are at end of line or `Ctrl+k` if you are at the beginning of line

Comment: @MarkPlotnick You should provide that as an answer. Sounds like the perfect solution.

Answer (score 14):

Typing the <kbd>Ctrl-U</kbd> key combination will, in most cases<sup>1</sup>, erase the entire line of input even if echo is turned off.

[1] Some programs put the terminal device into "raw" mode, where every character you type is sent to the program. Emacs is one example. They may have their own conventions for character erase/line kill processing.

Answer (score 3):

Another choice:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> : Delete everything till the first white space, basically, delete the last word.

Genrally useful shortcuts (don't work for password prompts):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> : Go to the beginning of the line
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> : Go to the end of the line
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> : Kill everything from the position of the cursor to the end of the line. Combine it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to delete everything.

Comment: emacs keys? position of the cursor? You know this question is about a non-echoing password prompt, right? Those things don't apply there. (Except for `^W` which is `stty werase` so it works almost as reliably as `^U`).

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley MarkPlotnicj has already given the best answer, I am offering some extra information that might be useful for other people who stumble upon this question. Yes, do know what the question is about, I actually read it and everything and Ctrl+W is what I use in these situations. Still, I'll clarify that the last 2 don't work for password prompts.

Answer (score 1):

Just type backspace more times than the lenght of the password you (mis-) typed, and start over.

I always add a few extra backspaces, just to be sure.

Mistyping happens to me mostly when I cannot type blind (e.g. on a client system with an AZERTY keyboard).